# What is an alternative to cast or use multiple constraint bounds in generic function in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, generics

I have three data classes, and I want create a generic function to map them:

```
data class Visits(
    val present: List<Present>,
    val past: List<Past>
)

data class Present{
    val field1: String,
    val field2: String
}

data class Past{
    val field1: String,
    val field2: String
}
```

The generic function I had tried something like

```
    private fun doSomething(visits: Visits, position: Int) {
        when (position) {
            0 -> setItems(visits.present)
            1 -> setItems(visits.past)
            ...
        }
    }

    private fun <T> setItems(visits: List<T>): ArrayList<Something> {
        val items: ArrayList<Something> = arrayListOf()
        
        visits.forEach { i ->
            items.add(
                Something(
                    i.field1,
                    i.field2
                )
            )
        }
        return items
    }
```

Overall thats the code, I've tried to use something like

```
    inline fun <reified T> doSomethingWithType(list: List<T>) {
     // do something with visits list, which can be List<Present> or List<Past>
    }
```

I would like to avoid having duplicated code for setItems function for example, setItemsPresent and setItemsPast.

Comment: I don't quite get what you're trying to do. What are you trying to map Present and Past to? What is Something? 

You may wanna take advantage of the standard kotlin list.map { } extension function, may make your problem a little easier.

Comment: The scenario is, Visits is an api response object, the ideia is to map those values in the lists (Present, Past) to differents tabs for example. What I called Something is a data class which is used for databinding. So, more specifically, there is a parent Fragment with TabLayout and ViewPager2. I intend to reuse one fragment for tabitems, so I'm using one viewmodel and passing the position to child fragments, one will have List<Present> items and the other List<Past>. I know there are another ways, but I'm trying to use generics and make kind of a reusable component.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to solve this with an interface,

```
interface Item {
    val field1: String
    val field2: String
}

data class Present(
    override val field1: String,
    override val field2: String
) : Item

data class Past(
    override val field1: String,
    override val field2: String
) : Item
```

Then your child fragment can take a list of type `List<Item>` and work whether they're Present or Past data objects.

There's then not much point to a generic map function, but so you know, what you need is more info about the generic through a generic constraint.

```
data class Something(
    val field1: String,
    val field2: String
)

fun <T : Item> mapToSomething(visits: List<T>): List<Something> {
    return visits.map { Something(it.field1, it.field2) }
}
```